# PHP refresh page prevent data insertion

Tags: php

So I have a form that once submitted is taken to another page and in that page there is a query that inserts data to a database, although when I refresh that page it still inputs empty data, how can I make it so if the page is refreshed to not input data or when the page is accessed without inputting the form.

Comment: Add your code, we can't guess what is wrong if you don't show what you've done.

Answer (score 0):

You need to seperate out your concerns, typically browsers will *always* save posted data to the `$_POST` array, so refreshing a page that has had data submitted to it will retain all the posted data and can easily cause multiple submissons.

To work round this you need to layout the logic in the following way:

```
 <page that has the HTML form on it> 
        ||
        \/
 <page that saves data but does NOT output anything to the browser.>
 This page will then user a PHP header to redirect to the next page...
        ||
        \/    
 <page which outputs to the browser but writes nothing to the database>
 So this page can be refreshed as much as you like, you will not get
 multiple writes to the database unless you repeat submitting the form
 via page 1
```

We can not solve why you're having empty data input into your database without seeing your code, but it will probably be wiser for you to read other Stack Overflow answers and very carefully check your code `If` statements for inconsistencies.